# I have two services, both running within a Docker Compose setup and connected to the same network, but they can't establish a connection

Tags: java, spring, docker, docker-compose, quarkus

Connection refused when sending http request from container to another container in the same network

```
 jakarta.ws.rs.ProcessingException: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:80
```

Here is the docker compose configurations:

```
services:
  keycloak_dev:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
    container_name: keycloak_dev
    ports:
      - "9090:8080"
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=test
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=test

    networks:
      - network1
    command: "start-dev"
  backend:
    image: test-app
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - keycloak_dev
    networks:
      - network1
networks:
  network1:
    name: quarkus-network
    driver: bridge
```

Here is my application.properties:

```
quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=http://keycloak_dev:8080/realms/Test
keycloak-client/mp-rest/url=http://keycloak_dev:8080
```

Here is my KeycloakClient in the backen service:

```
@RegisterRestClient(configKey = "keycloak-client")
@RegisterProvider(RequestLoggingFilter.class)
public interface KeycloakClient {

    @POST
    @Path("/realms/{realm}/protocol/openid-connect/token")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    AccessTokenResponse login(
            @PathParam("realm") String realm,
            MultivaluedMap<String, String> formParams
    );
```

When I print the request from RequestLoggingFilter:

```
2023-10-11 12:40:09 test-service-backend-1  | Requesting POST http://keycloak_dev:8080/realms/Test/protocol/openid-connect/token
2023-10-11 12:40:09 test-service-backend-1  | Content-Type: [application/x-www-form-urlencoded]
2023-10-11 12:40:09 test-service-backend-1  | User-Agent: [Resteasy Reactive Client]
2023-10-11 12:40:09 test-service-backend-1  | Request Entity: {password=[test], grant_type=[password], client_secret=[secret], client_id=[quarkus], username=[test]}
```

The error of Keycloak Client

```
jakarta.ws.rs.ProcessingException: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:80
```

The error of oidc:

```
(vert.x-eventloop-thread-1) Discovery has failed, status code: 404
2023-10-11 10:29:51 test-service-backend-1  | 2023-10-11 07:29:51,275 WARN  [io.qua.oid.com.run.OidcCommonUtils] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-1) OIDC Server is not available:: io.quarkus.oidc.common.runtime.OidcEndpointAccessException
 2023-10-11 10:29:52,155 WARN  [io.qua.oid.run.OidcRecorder] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-1) OIDC server is not available at the 'http://keycloak_dev:8080/realms/Test' URL. Please make sure it is correct.
```

My trials:

1. I tried changing the hostname keycloak_dev into localhost and it didn't work
2. I tried to open the command line and make an HTTP request to the Keycloak server from the backend container shell and see if it resolves correctly: by these commands:

   - docker exec -it test-service-backend-1 sh
   - curl -i keycloak_dev:8080
     and the result was HTTP 200 OK, and I tried a POST to the keycloak server and it worked successfully with the expected response
3. I tried a completely new service that only had a GET endpoint returning a String, and I replaced it with the Keycloak service to test if it could establish a connection with my backend service. However, it couldn't.

Hint: The backend is a quarkus service

Comment: if you will try to change url from `quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=http://keycloak_dev:8080/realms/Test` to `quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=http://keycloak_dev:9090/realms/Test` will it work ?

Comment: "Status code 404" suggests that the connection from one container to the other is successful (the host name and port are correct) but the URL path is wrong.

Comment: @AndreiLisa Connections between containers don't use `ports:` at all.  If the Keycloak service inside its container is listening on port 8080 then that's the correct port for the cross-service URL, even if it's being published to the host on a different port.

Comment: @AndreiLisa no it didn't

Comment: @DavidMaze what about the client problem I can make the same exact request with the same url in the command line with the curl and it works but i cant through my backend, you can see the log request done by the client and the one done by the curl

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the issue is to change the service name in the Docker Compose file from `keycloak_dev` to `keycloackdev`, removing the underscore.
I found it from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76991211/22723067